# Passing props to a webpacker react component in rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpacker

How do you pass props or data to the component when using the 
`javascript_pack_tag` tag?

currently

```
/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'flash_messages', data: {messages: flash_messages} %>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'CropImages' %>
    <%= content_tag :div,
      id: "appointments_data",
      data: @product.to_json,
      front_image: url_for(@product.front_image), 
      back_image: url_for(@product.back_image) do %>
   <% end %>
```

react component :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { 
const node = document.getElementById('appointments_data')
const data = JSON.parse(node.getAttribute('data'))
const frontImage = node.getAttribute('front_image')
const backImage = node.getAttribute('back_image')
ReactDOM.render(
  <CropImages data={data} front_image={frontImage} back_image={backImage} />,
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be done in several ways.

1.you could by pass props "by hand"

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const node = document.getElementById('flash_messages_data')
  const data = JSON.parse(node.getAttribute('data'))
   ReactDOM.render(
     <FlashMessages messages={data} />,
     document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
   )
  })
```

Or you could you gem, which basically does almost the same:
https://github.com/renchap/webpacker-react

in you view

```
<%= react_component('FlashMessages', { messages: [] }) %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'components/flash_messages' %>
```

and in your component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import WebpackerReact from 'webpacker-react'

class FlashMessages extends Component {
  ...
  render() {}
}

WebpackerReact.setup({FlashMessages}) // ES6 shorthand for {Hello: Hello}
```

last line basically parses data attribute generated by the `react_component` helper, and passes to your component.